# Using Both HorizontalDrag and VerticalDrag XNA

Tags: c#, xna, gesture

I am currently building a game using C#/XNA on VS2012 and on my code I want the user to touch an object and drag it vertically and horizontally without lifting the finger when switching to vertical or horizontal gesture. Here is a sample of my code:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // Move the sprite by speed, scaled by elapsed time. 
        //shipPosition += shipSpeed; 

        // check whether gestures are available
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            // read the next gesture
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            // has the user tapped the screen?
            switch (gesture.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:

                    shipPosition += gesture.Delta;

                    break;
                case GestureType.VerticalDrag:

                    shipPosition += gesture.Delta;

                    break;
            }
        }

        // Make sure that the ship does not go out of bounds 
        shipPosition.X = MathHelper.Clamp(shipPosition.X, 35 / 2 , 765 + 35 / 2 - shipTexture.Width);
        shipPosition.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(shipPosition.Y, 21 / 2, 451 + 21 / 2 - shipTexture.Height);

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Can someone please advise? I saw somewhere that I have to use raw input touch but I would like to know how that works with drags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Touch Location instead

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx

look under

> Getting Multitouch Data from the Touch Input Device

Comment: I have tried using the code below but it returns an error saying "cannot convert from 'float' to 'integer'. I made sure that the imageRect is in the place of position where the sprite is drawn and declared "Rectangle imageRect":

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->                                                                                TouchCollection touchLocations = TouchPanel.GetState();
            foreach(TouchLocation tl in touchLocations)
                {
                    Rectangle touchRect = new Rectangle 
                    (tl.Position.X, tl.Position.Y,10,10);

                  if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Moved && imageRect.Intersects(touchRect))
                  {
                        imageRect.X = touchRect.X;
                         imageRect.Y = touchRect.Y;
                    }
            }

Comment: I got it working using TouchLocations but it works the same as FreeDrag... so I while freedrag and then create a rectangle inside the parameter with 1pixel distance so it will give a path for the sprite to be moved along the rectangle edge and doubletap to release the collusion and create linear trails not curved. Do you know how can I do that? When I move the object to leave straight trails or stairs like even when I move it oblique?